# How to run specific code only when running from jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cucumber

I have below code that is used to invoke the chromedriver. Out of all the chrome options, I need to add force-device-scale-factor=0.70 and high-dpi-support=0.70 only when I run the test cases from jenkins mode.

Can someone please let me know how I can run specific code only when running from Jenkins?

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
        co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        co.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        // co.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        co.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.70");
        co.addArguments("high-dpi-support=0.70");
        co.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" 
        });
        co.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        tlDriver.set(new ChromeDriver(co));
```

Comment: You should be able to run the application with an specific profile. In that specific profile you should be able to set a property "runCodeX: true" and add conditional based on this property on the code.

Comment: Have Jenkins pass in a flag.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to depend on the presence of a given environment variable. For example `WORKSPACE`, `CI`, or `JENKINS_URL`. All of the are usually only set when built as part of a Jenkins job (I would use `CI`, since this is not Jenkins specific.

Put your code in an `if` block, where you check the presence of the chosen env- variable (System.getenv).